# How to make rotatable figures?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

I’m using javascript for writing a game. And I’m completely in trouble with such problem: 
If you click once on board (canvas) it draws circle and important is that it has to be rotatable (so that you can rotate it on four positions: 0, 90, 180, 270 degrees). Once the player has chosen the position, klicks secondly on the screen and the position will be fixed. The solution must not use the board like in illustration is demonstrated(it can be done just on clean canvas.)
I look forward to your response! your help would be really useful, and sorry if my question is stupid but I'm still just a beginner.
Thank you in advance for your response!

Here above is an illustration and the code(for drawing X and O):

[image: Illustration]

```js
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  onClick(event);
});
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 function drawX(x, y) {

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(x + -36, y + -35);

ctx.lineTo(x + 35, y + 36);

ctx.moveTo(x + -36, y + 35);

ctx.lineTo(x + 35, y + -36);

ctx.moveTo(x + -36, y + -35);

ctx.lineTo(x + 0, y - 75);

ctx.moveTo(x + 36, y + -35);

ctx.lineTo(x + 0, y - 75); 

ctx.moveTo(x + -36, y + -35);

ctx.lineTo(x + 35, y + -36);

ctx.stroke();

}

  function drawO(x, y, r) {

  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);

  ctx.strokeStyle = "Indigo";
   
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;

  ctx.moveTo(x + -36, y + -35);

ctx.lineTo(x + 0, y - 75);

ctx.moveTo(x + 36, y + -35);

ctx.lineTo(x + 0, y - 75); 
  
ctx.moveTo(x + -36, y + -35);

ctx.lineTo(x + 35, y + -36);

  ctx.stroke();

}

  var x = e.x - canvas.offsetLeft;

  var y = e.y - canvas.offsetTop;
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
```

Comment: i think you mean move (as in translate) the position of the x or o along the grid correct? rotating an x or an o 90 degrees would have no affect for either letter (as they are symmetric along these rotations)

Comment: I believe OP has a small needle that is pointing down in the picture and would like that rotated possibly. Obviously a circle does not need to be rotated though, just the needle. As for how to do this OP, you can just use a series of if statements to draw it up, down, left or right. You might need more of a pointed question to get more helpful answers as it is difficult to see what you are really asking.